# RewriteRule, can't make it work

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

URL:
http://mysite.com/amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/?id=9999

I need it to be rewritten to:
http://mysite.com/amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/?p=9999

I mean all of the urls of that type (with ID on the end)
My rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule http://mysite.com/amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/\?id=(.*) http://mysite.com/amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=\/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

So far looks legit, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Before that line I have 3 following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^members/(.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Update.
Tried this:

```
RewriteRule /amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/\?id=(\d+) /amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/\?id=(\d+) /amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

either

```
RewriteRule ^amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/\?id=(\d+) http://mysite.com/amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/?p=$1 [R=301,L]
```

either

UPDATED:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule /amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/ajax/$ /amember/login.php\?amember_redirect_url=/?p=%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: You may want to read [mod_rewrite based on query string parameters](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html).

Comment: Read, fixed the code, but still doesn't work. Update first post with what I have right now.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ [NC] this condition was not met

Comment: no idea what to do, tried so many different way and still won't met the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. If you are requesting `http://localhost/amember/login.php?something&foo`, the URI passed to a `RewriteRule` is only `/amember/logi.php`, therefore anything with a `\?` will not match unless there's an encoded `?` (via a %3F) in the URI.

Additionally, you have a *single* param in your query string:

`amember_redirect_url` = `/ajax/?p=9999`

The `?` inside the query string parameter's value isn't a parameter by itself because it's not separated by a `&`, so you need to match against that and rewrite that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)amember_redirect_url=/ajax/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?amember/login\.php$ /amember/login.php?%1amember_redirect_url=/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: almost works, except what I get is: http://mysite.com/amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/%3fid=4025 and I need to get http://mysite.com/amember/login.php?amember_redirect_url=/?p=4025

Comment: ok got it working RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)amember_redirect_url=/ajax/\?id=(.*) Thank you very much!

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya Add a `NE` into the square brackets: `[L,R=301,NE]`